# Book about a group mind arising from noninvasive brain-computer interfaces

Tags: story-identification, books

I would swear it started with an S, symbiosis, symbiont, synergy, something like that, but google has nothing for me.

The main character was a professional programmer. I think but am not certain her name was Jasmine. I am certain that her hardware broke, and she needed to get a replacement, but before she did, she noticed an increased intensity of qualia. She also noticed people who were connected paying attention to her. She found out that a mind had arisen from the internet, and was using a bit of people's brains to run itself on. Being aware of this got her conscripted into the mind's service, made to infiltrate a group working on an intentionally generated group mind that used a larger share of the brains of the people running it, but did so voluntarily rather than in secrecy. I remember vividly the scene with 'the witch', who taught her to lie over a direct brain interface by believing the lie herself, supporting it with details - the scene was about lying about her hair color, and at first she thought of it as exotic, but the witch corrected her - it was boring, the way it had always been.

She and a man who may be the son of the witch infiltrate this group successfully, and the group ends up connecting it to the larger internet, where it begins taking people over, trying to overthrow the primary mind.

Victory for humanity is achieved by sending a command through the system to people to take off their hardware, depriving the system of those resources.

Comment: Note you need two new lines to create a paragraph break. Really nice description, however, if there is anything else you can remember, like approximately how old it was you can [edit] that into the post.